# Error en Ejecutar el IIE

Tags: c#, webservice

Estoy ejecutando mi archivo ya subido en un IIE de manera local pero me sale ese error. quisiera me ayuden por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error 503 típicamente se refiere al `Pool` que se tiene configurado en el IIS o en su caso, la cuenta de usuario que tiene configurado el `Pool` ha expirado o su contraseña ya no es válida.

## Revisión del `Pool` asociado al sitio

1. En el IIS, da clic derecho a tu servicio
2. Selecciona `Manage`
3. `Advanced Settings`
4. En la sección `General` opción `Applicaion Pool`, donde aparece el nombre del `Pool` da clic para despleglar la información y en la parte que dice `Properties` revisa que la versión del `Pool` sea la misma que la versión en la que se publicó el servicio

## Configuración del `Pool`

1. Da clic en la sección `Applications Pools`
2. Se desplegará la lista de `Pools` registrados en el IIS
3. Clic derecho al `Pool` que estába configurado en el sitio
4. Seleccionar `Advanced Settings`
5. En la sección `General` opción `.NET CLR Version` ajusta la versión del `Pool` a la versión con la que se publicó el sitio Web/servicio/api etc.
6. Sección `Process Model` opción `Identity` donde aparece el nombre de la identidad da clic para ajustar las opciones de la identidad:
   `Built-in account`: seleccionará una identidad establecida por el sistema operativo o el IIS, comúnmente se tiene seleccionado `ApplicationPoolIdentity`
   `Custom Account`: seleccionará una identidad personalizada por el usuario, en este caso, es preferible seleccionar una cuenta de usuario que tenga permisos de administrador para evitar conflictos en escritura o lectura de archivos y carpetas